# Any reference that confirms that Array.Sort(charArray, StringComparer.Ordinal) works?

Tags: c#, stringcomparer

I would like to sort an array of chars according to their ordinal positions (code points) in Unicode table.

I see that the following code works:

```
char[] charArray = new[] { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
Array.Sort(charArray, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

But it looks a bit weird. First because both of these parameters are non-generic, and secondly, here I am using a StringComparer to compare chars.

Is this guaranteed to work? Any reference?

Comment: `StringComparer` in given example just offload comparison to `IComparable.CompareTo` ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/stringcomparer.cs,91)). You can as well use default comparer.

Comment: @PetSerAl wow what a badly designed API. StringComparer should *fail* if invoked with non-strings.

Comment: So I guess the answer is: This works but don't do that.

Comment: Ok, but then, what is the proper way to sort an array of characters according to their ordinal (Unicode code point number)? `.OrderBy(chr => chr)`? `Array.Sort(charArray)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy(chr => chr)` does the trick. `char` is `IComparable` and that comparable definition compares the integer/"ordinal" value of the chars.